# Creating a case insensitive full-text index with analyzer 'whitespace'

Tags: indexing, neo4j

- Neo4j Version: 4.4.2.
- Edition: Enterprise

---

Currently I'm trying to implement a case-insensitive full-text index with the 'whitespace' analyzer.

```
 CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX carIndex FOR (c:Car) ON EACH [c.ShortDescription, c.Name] OPTIONS { indexConfig: {`fulltext.analyzer`: 'whitespace'}}
```

When hitting this index it seems that it is case-sensitive.
Looking at the [Full-text search](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-full-text-search/) index documentation I'm unable to find what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to create an index which is case insensitive and tokanizes on whitespace?

---

Other sources I've looked through:

[Full-text index analyzer providers](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/full-text-analyzer-provider/)

[Custom analyzer for fulltext search in Neo4j](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/09/06/custom-fulltext-analyzer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link shows you to create a plugin(like the APOC) which you can add to your database. This way you can create your own analyzer for your index.

[Custom - analyzers](https://github.com/covidgraph/neo4j-additional-analyzers/tree/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/contrib/analyzers)

Comment: @David this should do